# Flash Air for Android, how to send SMS

Tags: android, flash

I'm developing an Android App by using Flash Air 2.6. How to implement SMS functionality?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b24b55b57a124b32b5b57-7ffe.html

```
str = "sms:1-415-555-1212"; 
var urlReq:URLReq = new URLRequest(str); 
navigateToURL(urlReq);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to embed text in the message?

Answer (score 0):

Air android native extension:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gwkyz74r3ajp4p7/com.adobe.sendsms.ANESendSms.ane

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

AS3:

```
import com.adobe.sendsms.ANESendSms;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;

private function sendSms():void {
   var sms:ANESendSms = new ANESendSms();
   sms.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, statusHandle);
   sms.sendSms("667250202", "txt");
}

private function statusHandle(e:StatusEvent):void {
   if (e.level == "sent_-1") {// sent ok
   }
   if (e.level == "delivered_-1") {// delivered ok
   }
}
```